# Changing a certain item in a text file list

Tags: list, python-3.x, append, binary-search

I have a code to try and change a certain item in a list in a text file. The text file contains email,password on each line sort of like a login system.
The code asks for a users input for an email then binary searches for that user in the list in the text file. If the user is present then I want to change the password for that user so append the [1] item on the list.
Here is my code for changing the password so far

```
def ChangePassword():

    while True:
        email=input("Enter the email you want to change the password for")
        res=BinarySearch(logindata,email)
        if res:
            break
```

I know it isnt much but I havent a clue how to do this , how would I approach this?
Here is my code for the Binary Search itself if needed.

```
def BubbleSort(logindata):
    NoSwaps = 1
    N = len(logindata)
    logindata = list(logindata)
    while NoSwaps == 1:
        Count = 1
        NoSwaps = 0
        for Count in range(N-1):
            if logindata[Count] > logindata[Count+1]:
                temp = logindata[Count]
                logindata[Count] = logindata[Count+1]
                logindata[Count+1]=temp
                NoSwaps=1
    return tuple(logindata)

def BinarySearch(logindata,email):
    First=0
    Last=len(logindata)-1
    while First <= Last:
        Midpoint = (First + Last) // 2
        if logindata[Midpoint][0] == email:
            print("Email Found")
            return True   
        elif logindata[Midpoint][0] > email:
            Last = Midpoint - 1
        else:
            First = Midpoint + 1
    print("Not found")
    return False
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the file is sorted? Anyway python built-ins are probably (at least) as fast as your implementation in any case. Why are you implementing the search again?

Comment: Because I have to use a binary search that is the point of it , I know its annoying even if it isnt as efficient, and about the file being sorted it should be as the bubble sort sorts it alphabetically? @kabanus

Comment: So to be clear, you read a file, bubble sort it, binary look for e-mails and change an item, then write the result (to a new file, or the original one)?

Comment: yes that is right that is what i would like to do , to the original file @kabanus

Comment: @kabanus TypeError: invalid file - this is the error I get with your answer

Comment: This is a template, you were supposed to send the file name to the function (you said it exists). If you're just copy pasting without realizing what the code does then you need to go back to some tutorials.